# how to extract json data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have some stream data from that i want to retrieve 
`"estimatedResultCount":"399"` from this below data

how to get 399 value from this approach 
  parsing the JSON -> responseData -> cursor -> estimatedResultCount will get you backing count.

```
{
        "responseData": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "GsearchResultClass": "GwebSearch",
                    "unescapedUrl": "http://www.homeocare.in/",
                    "url": "http://www.homeocare.in/",
                    "visibleUrl": "www.homeocare.in",
                    "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:E7xF9dtFWgIJ:www.homeocare.in",
                    "title": "Homeopathy Clinics in Hyderabad - Homeopathy Treatment",
                    "titleNoFormatting": "Homeopathy Clinics in Hyderabad - Homeopathy Treatment",
                    "content": "Homeocare International - World Class Homeopathy Clinic in India provides \ninformation on causes, symptoms, and Homeopathy treatment of various \ndiseases."
                },
                {
                    "GsearchResultClass": "GwebSearch",
                    "unescapedUrl": "http://www.homeocare.in/contactus.html",
                    "url": "http://www.homeocare.in/contactus.html",
                    "visibleUrl": "www.homeocare.in",
                    "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:zrjNDKonZY0J:www.homeocare.in",
                    "title": "Homeocare International | Contact Us",
                    "titleNoFormatting": "Homeocare International | Contact Us",
                    "content": "To get best Homeopathy treatment Contact Homeocare International through \nphone or fill contact form. We have branches all over South India."
                },
                {
                    "GsearchResultClass": "GwebSearch",
                    "unescapedUrl": "http://www.homeocare.in/testimonials.html",
                    "url": "http://www.homeocare.in/testimonials.html",
                    "visibleUrl": "www.homeocare.in",
                    "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:oPJKzW6sHOkJ:www.homeocare.in",
                    "title": "Homeocare International Reviews / Testimonials",
                    "titleNoFormatting": "Homeocare International Reviews / Testimonials",
                    "content": "Homeocare International Reviews / Testimonials for Happy Patient. We pride \nourselves on excellent service, and our reviews show it!"
                },
                {
                    "GsearchResultClass": "GwebSearch",
                    "unescapedUrl": "http://www.homeocare.in/arthritis.html",
                    "url": "http://www.homeocare.in/arthritis.html",
                    "visibleUrl": "www.homeocare.in",
                    "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:gqHnM_Tg0hcJ:www.homeocare.in",
                    "title": "Homeopathy Treatment for Arthritis | Arthritis Treatment",
                    "titleNoFormatting": "Homeopathy Treatment for Arthritis | Arthritis Treatment",
                    "content": "Get Homeopathy Treatment for arthritis and rheumatoid arthritis at Homeocare \nInternational provides safe and effective remedies with no side effects."
                }
            ],
            "cursor": {
                "resultCount": "399",
                "pages": [
                    {
                        "start": "0",
                        "label": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "4",
                        "label": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "8",
                        "label": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "12",
                        "label": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "16",
                        "label": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "20",
                        "label": 6
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "24",
                        "label": 7
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "28",
                        "label": 8
                    }
                ],
                "estimatedResultCount": "399",
                "currentPageIndex": 0,
                "moreResultsUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?oe=utf8&ie=utf8&source=uds&start=0&hl=en&q=site:homeocare.in",
                "searchResultTime": "0.09"
            }
        },
    "responseDetails": null,
    "responseStatus": 200
    }
```

**Code**

```
string strurl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:homeocare.in";
             StreamReader stream = objm.URLServerRequest(strurl);
             string myResponse = stream.ReadToEnd();

   public StreamReader URLServerRequest(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            return stream;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the class here http://json2csharp.com/, it's very easy.

Given that you succesfully download the json string, here's the code as a console application. It uses json.net (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/7.0.1-beta2)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @".... json string....";
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.responseData.cursor.estimatedResultCount)
                ;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Result
    {
        public string GsearchResultClass { get; set; }
        public string unescapedUrl { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string visibleUrl { get; set; }
        public string cacheUrl { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string titleNoFormatting { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
    }
    public class Page
    {
        public string start { get; set; }
        public int label { get; set; }
    }
    public class Cursor
    {
        public string resultCount { get; set; }
        public List<Page> pages { get; set; }
        public string estimatedResultCount { get; set; }
        public int currentPageIndex { get; set; }
        public string moreResultsUrl { get; set; }
        public string searchResultTime { get; set; }
    }
    public class ResponseData
    {
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
        public Cursor cursor { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public ResponseData responseData { get; set; }
        public object responseDetails { get; set; }
        public int responseStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can i apply it in web application, i just need public string estimatedResultCount { get; set; }
 @Paolo Coasta

Comment: Sure, just extract the code in a function and you can call it from wherever you want

Comment: @PaoloCosta, did you use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate the class structure? If so, include it in your answer please so that future readers know how to easily generate them :)

Comment: Yes,sorry I forgot to say that, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Wow that's a great tool!